# How to manage std::vector of std::function

Tags: c++, class, vector, operator-overloading

I'm moving from a class hierarchy for solving ODE to a class to solve a system of ODEs.

In my implementation to work with a single function, I use the following to store my function:

```
std::function<const Type(const Type, const Type)> numericalFunction
```

I have a wrapper to evaluate the numerical function:

```
Type f (Type t, Type u) const noexcept { return numericalFunction(t,u); }
```

---

Now I'm moving to solving a system of equations, so I need to store multiple functions. I tried to store the set of functions using a `std::vector` as given below:

```
std::vector<std::function<const Type(const Type,const Type)>> numericalFunction;
```

I want to be able to use the same syntax as used in the above question. That is,

`f[0](12,32);` should execute `numericalFunction.at(0)(12,32);`

`dfdt[0](t, u);` should execute  `(numericalFunction.at(0)(t, u+eps) - numericalFunction.at(0)(t, u))/eps;`

How can I write the code to allow such a syntax?

**EDIT** I have a problem .. now I need to change the function

```
std::vector<std::function<const Type(const Type,const Type)>> numericalFunction;
```

becames :

```
std::vector<std::function<const Type(const Type,const std::vector<Type>)>> numericalFunction;
```

and the derivative class doesn't works

Comment: `return numericalFunction.at(0)(t,u);` has no meaning with `numericalFunction` being a `std::function`.

Comment: `Type    f (size_t function_id, Type t, Type u) const noexcept { numericalFunction.at(function)(t,u); }` Will this do? As @YSC said, `at` is not a member function of `std::function`.

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what you're asking

Comment: `auto numFun1 = [](double t , double u) {return -20*u+20*sin(t)+cos(t) ; } ;` shouldn't be `auto numFun1 = [](double t , double u)->double {return -20*u+20*sin(t)+cos(t) ; } ;`?

Comment: How do you want to select a function? Are the function's given a unique id? If yes, do they start from 0 and are they continuous?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store a collection of functions as:

```
std::vector<std::function<const Type(const Type t, const Type u)>> numericalFunList;
```

Your equivalent function to obtain the correct function will be:

```
const Type f(size_t idx, const Type t, const Type u) { return numericalFunList.at(idx)(t,u); }
```

The `std::vector` is internally a dynamic array. This gives each function an index starting from `0` till `numericalFunList.size() - 1`. You can identify each function by its index in the vector.

---

**EDIT1:**

The OP prefers to use the following syntax: `f[0](arg1, arg2);`

The above can be easily achieved: `numericalFunList[0](1.2, 5.9);`

If `f` is needed for clarity (for mathematicians; programmers would hate it),

```
auto& f = numericalFunList;
f[0](10.9, 2.4);
```

As a tip, consider not using `f` as a variable name globally. If `f` is the preferred, use `auto& f = numericalFunList` to do it for you.

---

**EDIT2:**

For the new syntax requirements, you need to use two classes each with one operator overload: one to store the set of derivatives with `[]` operator overloaded and the other to compute the derivative with `()` operator overloaded.

```
typedef long double Type;
constexpr Type eps = 1E-12;

using analysisFunction = std::function<const Type(const Type, const Type)>;

class derivatives {
    private:
        class derivative;
    public:
        derivatives(std::vector<analysisFunction>& p_fList) { fList = &p_fList; };
        derivative operator[](int index) {
            return derivative((*fList).at(index));
        }
    private:
        class derivative {
            public:
                derivative(analysisFunction& p_f) { f = &p_f; }
                Type operator()(Type t, Type u) {
                    return (((*f)(t, u + eps)) - ((*f)(t,u)))/eps;
                }
            private:
                analysisFunction *f;
        };
        std::vector<analysisFunction> *fList; //dangling pointer
};
```

**Example usage**

```
int main ()
{
    std::vector <analysisFunction> numericalFunctions;
    auto& f = numericalFunctions;

    f.push_back([](Type t, Type u)->Type { return u*u; });


    std::cout << std::setprecision(16);
    std::cout << f[0](5.0, 10.0) << '\n';

    derivatives dfdt(f);
    std::cout << dfdt[0](5.0, 10.0);
    return 0;
}
```

Testing code: [GeeksForGeeks Online IDE](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/ieu0Ac4iMj)

Note: `fList` is a dangling pointer. There are several ways to deal with it. You can leave it as it is if you can guarantee that the referenced object wouldn't be deallocated or you can maintain a copy in the object (which would cost memory and CPU).

Comment: yes using a map could be better than using the id inside the argument ! how can I set the map ?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your keys in your question? Note that `std::map` is usually implemented as trees and will provide you O(log n) complexity for searching whereas an `std::unordered_map` is implemented as a hashmap  will give you O(1) complexity on average.

Comment: Do adjacent numbers strictly increase by one? Will it be sort of `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` or `3, 7, 9, 12, 13, 14`?

Comment: adiacent basically I have just to make coherence between the key and the index of the function that I'm going to call

Comment: Then `std::vector` is the container for you. It will give you constant time lookups but it will require your numbers to start from `0` and strictly increase by one for every adjacent number pair.

Comment: This answer (and the OP's code) would be a lot easier to read if there was a typedef.

Comment: I would just have a way to define the function f above that take 2 argument and in same way indexing the vector of std::function

Comment: How do you even choose a function from the list of functions then?

Comment: is not possible using for example ` f[0] (Type i,Type j) { return numericalFun.at(0)(i,j)}`

Comment: That is not valid C++ syntax. You can do this though: `auto& f = numericalFun;` and then use `f[0](i, j);`

Comment: @MartinBonner `typedef` for the function?

Comment: @Drudoxlebowsky Don't use edits to reply. Add all your requirements to your question.

Comment: ok sorry ! now how can i deal with : `Type dfdt(Type t, Type u) const noexcept { return (f(t,u+eps)-f(t,u))/eps ; }`

Comment: I am assuming you want a syntax like this: `dfdt[0](123, 34);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161025/discussion-between-yashas-and-drudox-lebowsky).

Comment: typedef for the thing stored in the vector and returned from `f`

Comment: @MartinBonner I added `using analysisFunction` to replace the `std::function`. For the value returned by `f`, isn't `Type` already there?

Comment: I misunderstood what `f` was doing.  I thought it was returning the function, not applying it.